# Add values to an array

Tags: javascript

How to add values to an empty array? I have tried the following but it is not working:

```
var student = [{}];
for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    student[i].name = i;
    student[i].id = "1";
    student.push(student[i]);
} 

var a = JSON.stringify(student);
alert(a);
```

It give output 6 time repeated last values not 5 time :

```
'[{"name":4,"id":"1"},{"name":4,"id":"1"},{"name":4,"id":"1"},{"name":4,"id":"1"},{"name":4,"id":"1"},{"name":4,"id":"1"}]'
```

Comment: The problem has nothing to do with JSON. The issue is that you don't know how objects work. I recommend to read some tutorials about arrays and objects, such as http://eloquentjavascript.net/chapter4.html and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var student = [{}];
```

This creates a javascript array containing one empty object

```
student[i].name = i;
student[i].id = "1";
```

For `i = 0`, this alters that empty object.

```
student.push(student[i]);
```

You then push that altered object to the array it already exists in. You now have two identical values in the array.

Two items after first push. This is repeated five times.

Pushing an item adds it to the array. There's usually no point in pushing an element that's already in the array. Create a new object and push that. The array doesn't have to be pre-populated with an empty object to modify.

```
var student = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    student.push({
        name: i,
        id: '1'
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your original code, you are setting the object at student[i]'s values, then just pushing it again onto the array, then setting those values all over again.

You need to push a new object each time:

```
var student = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    student.push({
        id: i,
        name: i
    });
}

var a = JSON.stringify(student);
alert(a);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using the same name for the list and the new object. When you change the name of the list to students, your problem is fixed. Solution below:

```
var students = [{}];
for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    student = {}
    student.name = i;
    student.id = "1"; 
    students.push(student);
} 

var a = JSON.stringify(students);
alert(a);
```

Comment: `student` is not defined here.

Answer (score 0):

try ;

```
 var students = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) { 
        student = {}
        student.name = i;
        student.id = "1"; 
        students.push(student);
    } 

    var a = JSON.stringify(students);
    alert(a);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your array is not empty. It already contains an object. Maybe the problem is easier to see if we put the object in an extra variable and omit the the loop:

```
var student = [];
var obj = {};

obj.name = 1;
student.push(obj);

obj.name = 2;
student.push(obj)
```

The question is: How many objects are we creating here? The answer is *one*, namely `var obj = {};`. We then add some properties to the object (`name`) and add it to the array (`student.push(obj)`).

What comes next is crucial: We change the *existing properties* of the object and assign different values to it. Then we add the object to the array *again*. Even though `student` contains two elements, but they refer to the same value (which can be easily verified with `student[0] === student[1]`).

If you want to create an array of different objects, you have to *create* those objects. In our example this would be:

```
var student = [];
var obj = {};

obj.name = 1;
student.push(obj);

obj = {};          // <- create a new object
obj.name = 2;
student.push(obj)
```

For your code that means that you have to create a new object in each iteration of the loop, not just one outside of it.

---

Reading material about arrays and objects:

- [Eloquent JavaScript - Data structures: Objects and Arrays](http://eloquentjavascript.net/chapter4.html)
- [MDN - Working with objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects)
- [MDN - Array object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Predefined_Core_Objects#Array_Object)

Answer (score 0):

Since you are pushing object, its reference change every time to current value so at last it shows the output as last value.

Try this

```
         var student = [{}];
         for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            var obj = new Object();
            obj.name = i;
            obj.id = "1";
            student.push(students);
         }

         var a = JSON.stringify(student);
         alert(a);
```